# How to move a file to cron.d in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, raspbian

`my_cron`-file **works when it's created directly** in `/etc/cron.d/`:

```
sudo nano /etc/cron.d/my_cron

# Add content:
* * * * * username /path/to/python /path/to/file 2>/path/to/log
```

But it **doesn't work when I copy/move it** to the directory:

```
sudo cp ./my_cron /etc/cron.d/my_cron
```

`ls -l /etc/cron.d` outputs the **same permissions** both times: `-rw-r--r--`. The files are owned by `root`.

The only reason I could imagine at the moment is that I've to refresh/activate something after copying, which happens automatically on creation.

*Tested on Ubuntu and Raspbian.*

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older `cron` daemons used to examine `/etc/cron.d` for updated content only when they saw that the last-modified timestamp of that directory, or of the `/etc/crontab` file, had changed since the last time `cron` scanned it.  Recent `cron` daemons also examine the timestamps of the individual files in `/etc/cron.d` but maybe you're dealing with an old one here.

If you have an old `cron`, then if you copied a brand new file into `/etc/cron.d` then the directory's timestamp should change and `cron` should notice the new file. 
 However, if your `cp` was merely overwriting an existing file then that would not change the directory timestamp and `cron` would not pick up the new file content.

Editing a file in-place in `/etc/cron.d` would not necessarily update the directory timestamp, but some editors (certainly `vi`, unless you've configured it otherwise) will create temporary working files and perhaps a backup file in the directory where the file being edited lives.  The creation and deletion of those other files will cause the directory timestamp to be updated, and that will cause `cron` to put the edited file into effect.  This could explain why editing behaves differently for you than `cp`'ing does.

To force a timestamp to be updated you could do something like `sudo touch /etc/crontab` or create and immediately remove a scratch file (or a directory) in `/etc/cron.d` after you've `cp`'ed or `rm`'ed a file in there.  Obviously `touch` is easier.  If you want to go the create+delete route then `mktemp` would be a good tool to use for that, in order to avoid clobbering someone else's legitimate file.

If you were really paranoid, you'd wait at least a second between making file changes and then doing whatever you choose to do to force a timestamp update.  That should avoid the situation where a `cron` rescan, your file updates, and your `touch` or scratch create+delete could all happen within the granularity of the timestamp.

If you want to see what your `cron` is actually doing, you can `sudo strace -p <pid-of-cron>`.  Mostly it sleeps for a minute at a time, but you'll see it `stat` some files and directories (including `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d`) each time it wakes up.  And of course if it decides that it needs to run a job, you'll see that activity too.